# Visualisation tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Based on the answer to [Synonym merging suggestion for users with under 2.5k?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/990/synonym-merging-suggestion-for-users-with-under-2-5k)...

I noticed the recent creation of a [visualisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualisation) tag and also a little used [data-visualisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualisation), both spelled with an "s". Can this be a synonym or merged with [data-visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks.  I merged [visualisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visualisation) and [data-visualisation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualisation) with [data-visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization).